# Does Damping Force Affect Period of Oscillation of this pendulum?

Tags: forces, angular-momentum, harmonic-oscillator, drag

These are the results I obtained:

[image]

The blue line is the x-axis, i.e. when I let the mass hang without it swinging. 
The only thing damping it is air. The force measured, is the force exerted by the bob.

[image]

Above is a picture of the set-up (not very good, sorry). 
The set-up was a mass-on-string.
Mass: 1.82N
Length of string (approximately): 1.7m

Comment: What's the source of the damping?   Also note that the size of the force is not the only difference between forward and backwards.

Comment: Presumably your spring doesn't obey Hooke's law (specifically the symmetry requirement).

Comment: How come the force is never zero? This would mean that your system does not oscillate around the equilibrium position. Can you specify the setup?

Comment: Each cycle looks quite symmetrical to me. I think what you are observing is a small decrease in period as the amplitude of oscillations gets smaller. This is to be expected of a real pendulum or a real spring which (as lemon says) departs from Hooke's Law as amplitude increases. It would be useful to know what your setup is and what 'force' you are measuring.

Comment: Yes, but somehow the negative amplitude of each cycle is smaller than the positive amplitude. I'm sure there's a straight forward answer to this problem but i'm just not picking up on it. Maybe involving the mass of the pendulum... ?

Comment: I suspect that whatever is measuring the force either has a very asymmetric response or is very nonlinear.  Also the swinging-over-a-pulley thing would worry me.

Comment: But the swinging over a pulley doesn't affect the force exerted, right? I'm writing my Extended Essay on this and I can repeat the experiments but it would be good if I can explain why this may be other than simply blaming it on the technology.

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by "alteration of length approx. 3cm" in your diagram? How did you measure force? What was the purpose of your experiment?

Comment: Well, because it's over a pulley, the length  of the pendulum changes by approx 3cm in each swing. I measured the force by attaching a force sensor to the end of the string (behind the pulley on the left on the diagram), which was in turn plugged into my computer. Using logger pro, the graph was drawn automatically.

Comment: I see. The alteration of length is how much the string wraps around the pulley, as shown in your diagram. That changes the value of $L$ during each oscillation, so the period is slightly longer on the right when $L$ is longer (asymmetry!). But 3cm in 170cm is fairly small .... What about the purpose of the experiment? Was the object just to measure how the force exerted by the string changes during one oscillation? Or how it changes as the amplitude decreases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any asymmetry in your graph. What I do see is that as the amplitude of oscillations decreases then so does (1) the period and (2) the average tension in the string ("force") during one oscillation.

(1) Although for small amplitudes $\theta_0$ (in radians) the period $T$ is approximately constant (independent of $\theta_0$), for [larger amplitudes the period is longer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Power_series_solution_for_the_elliptic_integral) :
$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}[1+\frac{1}{16}\theta_0^2+\frac{11}{3072}\theta_0^4+...]$....(eqn 1)

This is because the restoring force is proportional to $\sin\theta$ rather than $\theta$. When the amplitude gets to $90^{\circ}$ the period is almost $20$% above its small-angle value.

(2) The tension $F$ in the string ("force") is the sum of the component of the weight $mg$ of the bob along the string plus the centripetal force required to keep the bob moving in a circle of radius $L$ with speed $v$ :
$F=mg\cos\theta+\frac{mv^2}{L}$....(eqn 2)

Since angular displacement $\theta=\theta_0\sin(\omega t)$, force $F$ is not a strictly sinusoidal function. Here $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T} \approx \sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}$ is the angular frequency of the pendulum. $v$ is related to displacement $\theta$ by
$v=L\frac{d\theta}{dt}$
$\frac{v^2}{L}=L\omega^2\theta_0^2\cos^2(\omega t)=g(\theta_0^2-\theta^2)$
therefore
$F=mg(\cos\theta+\theta_0^2-\theta^2)$...(eqn 3).

Note that $\omega$ is not equal to $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$. $\omega$ is related to the period of the pendulum and is constant if amplitude is constant, whereas $\theta$ is angular displacement and $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ is angular velocity of the bob, both of which vary sinusoidally during one oscillation.

Tension is greatest in each cycle when the bob swings through the vertical position $(\theta=0)$ :
$F_{max}=mg(1+\theta_0^2)$....(eqn 4)
Tension is least in each cycle when the bob reaches the maximum displacement $(\theta=\theta_0, v=0)$ :
$F_{min}=mg\cos\theta_0$....(eqn 5)

As amplitude decreases, $F_{max}$ decreases but $F_{min}$ increases. When the pendulum stops $(\theta_0=0,v=0)$ the tension is $F=F_{max}=F_{min}=mg=1.82N$, which is the value for the blue line on your graph.

[image]

The graph above shows how the force in Newtons varies with time in seconds, starting from an amplitude of 45 degrees, with a value for damping of $\gamma=0.05$ (which is considerably higher than in your results). I have used the small-angle value for the period throughout. Note that the average force decays from about 2.1N to about 1.82N.

---

You have not explained the purpose of your experiment, so it is not clear how you intend to make use of your results, which show how $F$ varies with time $t$ rather than with amplitude $\theta_0$.

(i) You could investigate the damping by rearranging eqns 3 & 4 to find how $\theta_0(t)$ varies with time. The 2 eqns should give the same values for $\theta_0$; you could calculate both and use the average.

If the damping force is proportional to the speed of the bob (which is what is expected for air resistance at 'low' speeds) you should get an exponential decay $\theta_0 \propto e^{-\gamma t}$ where $\gamma$ is the decay constant. So a plot of $\ln(\theta_0)$ against $t$ should be a straight line with -ve slope.

(ii) You could investigate how the period $T$ varies with amplitude $\theta_0$, by comparing your results with the prediction in eqn 1. Again you need to obtain $\theta_0(t)$ from the values of $F_{max}$ and $F_{min}$.

It is probably best to average the period over a few oscillations. Note also that force $F$ reaches a maximum twice in each oscillation of the pendulum, so **the period of the pendulum will be twice that in your graphs**.

Comment: So that means that the blue line is not actually my x-axis for the other graphs.

Comment: @Anna : Sorry I don't know what other graphs you need to plot.

Comment: I mean the other graphs on the graph. The green, red, pink and orange line ...

Comment: Those are the same graph of the pendulum, but at later times. The average value of force during one oscillation (what you are calling the x axis) decreases as amplitude decreases. The oscillations should not be symmetrical about the blue line, as you assumed. There is nothing going wrong with your graph, no technical problem caused by the equipment or the apparatus. The graph is exactly what you should expect : as amplitude $\theta_0$ decreases then $F_{max}$ decreases, $F_{min}$ increases, and average force $\frac12(F_{max}+F_{min})$ decreases.

Comment: What formula did you use for the period? The link doesn't work.

Comment: I used the small-amplitude period $T \approx 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$ - or rather $\omega \approx \sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}$ - to simplify the expression for $F$. It is only an approximation, because $T$ does actually change with amplitude. But it should be good enough to describe how $F_{max}$ and $F_{min}$ change with amplitude $\theta_0$, which we can assume decays exponentially with time : $\theta_0=\Theta_0 e^{-\gamma t}$.

Comment: I mean in number (1) you multiplied what is inside the square root by constants 1/16, 11/3072 etc. For larger amplitudes. Where did you get those numbers from?

Comment: Same numbers appear in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Power_series_solution_for_the_elliptic_integral). If you want to calculate values for large amplitude period, note the link below to the arithmetic-geometric mean solution, which converges much faster (although, it is more difficult to understand).

Comment: v2L=Lω2θ20cos2(ωt)

Comment: Where do you get this equation from? The second step from equation 3.

Comment: Combine $\theta=\theta_0\sin(\omega t)$ with $v=L\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, and note that $\omega$ is approximately constant.

Comment: and also equ. 3 , why is it equal to v2L=Lω2θ02cos2⁡(ωt)=g(θ02−θ2)

Comment: (meant to ask that before as well)

Comment: From last comment $v=L\omega \theta_0 \cos(\omega t)$ therefore $\frac{v^2}{L}=L\omega^2 \theta_0^2 \cos^2(\omega t)=g\theta_0^2(1-\sin^2(\omega t))=g(\theta_0^2-(\theta_0 \sin(\omega t))^2)=g(\theta_0^2-\theta^2)$. I have used the fact that $\omega^2=\frac{g}{L}$ approximately.

Comment: where did you get the assumption v=L dθ/dt from?

Comment: In circular motion the tangential velocity $v$ and angular velocity $\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ are related by $v=r\omega$. In this case $r=L$.

Answer (score -1):

Because your damping arrangement produces an inconsistent damping force between one direction and the other.